# how to make all of the pie charts in a one row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, charts

I'm using Chart.js for my website.
I'm trying to make all the charts in one row but I didn't figure out how to do it with it.
I have tried to use inline-block in couple variations but still, it didn't work.
Here is an example of the charts.

[image]

The html,CSS and js code are below:
html

```
<div class="chart-container">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.chart-container{
  display:inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.myCanvas{
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

js

```
function createChart(data, id,i) {
  addCanvas(id); // some id generated by you or sent by the user
  generateChart(data, id,i); // data from the user
}

function addCanvas(id) { // create the new canvas
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.id=id;
  canvas.classList.add('myCanvas');
  canvas.style = "width:20px; height:20px;";

  document.body.appendChild(canvas); // adds the canvas to the body element
  document.getElementsByClassName('chart-container')[0].appendChild(canvas);
}

function generateChart(data, id,i) { // initialize the new chart
  let piechart = $("#" + id);
  let data1 = {
    labels: namesArr,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Population (millions)",
        backgroundColor:
        ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850","#3cba9f"],
        data: data
      }
    ]
  };
  let chart = new Chart(piechart,{
    type:"pie",
    data : data1,
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: itemsArr[i]
      }
    }
  });
  chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '200px';
  chart.canvas.parentNode.style.width = '200px';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no snippet or working example, but try this:

```css
.chart-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* or space-between, center, depends on your needs */
}
```

With `display: flex` enabled, it has `flex-direction: row` as a default value, so it's not needed. But if you want it as column in the future, add `flex-direction: column`.